# Подскажите ,как через JS заменить содержимое .zoom-image <img src""> на содержимое .swiper-slide <image data-src"">

Tags: javascript

Подскажите ,как через JS заменить содержимое .zoom-image <img src""> на содержимое .swiper-slide <image data-src"">

```html
  <div class="zoom-image">
    <img src="./img/window-info-img.png">
</div>
            <div class="container">
                <p class="subtitle">MasterLine 10</p>
                <div class="window-info-block">
                    <div class="swiper-container window-info-block__slider">
                        <div class="swiper-wrapper">
                            <!-- Slides -->
                            <div class="swiper-slide ">
                                <img src="<%= require('./img/default.svg') %>"
                                     data-src="<%= require('./img/window-info-img.png') %>"
                                     alt="example" title="example" tabindex="0">
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Просто укажите нужные селекторы и data-атрибуты:

```js
document.querySelector('.zoom-image > img').src = document.querySelector('.swiper-slide > img').dataset.src;
```